# Smooth animation of a network using networkx and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, networkx

I am trying to animate the layout changes of a `networks` graph. My test code is as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import networkx as nx
import random
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

node_number = 0
G =nx.Graph()
G.add_node(node_number, Position=np.asarray([random.randrange(0,100), random.randrange(0,100)]))

while True:
    if node_number < 50:
        node_number += 1
        G.add_node(node_number, Position=np.asarray([random.randrange(0,100), random.randrange(0,100)]))
        ns=list(G.nodes())
        ns.remove(node_number)
        G.add_edge(node_number, random.choice(ns))
    else:
        break

source_pos = list(nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'Position').values())
target_pos = list(nx.circular_layout(G).values())
def anim(t):
    global source_pos
    global target_pos
    interpolation = np.asarray(source_pos)*(1-t) + np.asarray(target_pos)*t
    plt.clf()
    plt.cla()
    nx.draw(G, pos=interpolation)
    ax= plt.gca()
    ax.collections[0].set_edgecolor("#000000")

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, anim, repeat=False, frames=300, interval=20)
plt.show()
```

The code generates a weird transition no matter how I adjust the intervals or frames of the animation. I am attaching the output for the above code. Could anyone please help me with the mistake I am making?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `t` at the `anim` function, you pass a frame number so that you have to divide it by frames count in this line:

```py
interpolation = np.asarray(source_pos)*(1-t/299) + np.asarray(target_pos)*t/299
```

(since `frames` count is 300: 0 to 299)

Additionaly, you could use `while node_number < 50:` and remove test part instead of `while True`

**EDIT**
So I use `random.random()` to get a random position between -1 and 1.
The animation is far better.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import networkx as nx
import random
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

G =nx.Graph()
node_number = 0
while node_number < 50:
        G.add_node(node_number,
                   Position=np.asarray([random.random() * 2 -1,
                                        random.random() * 2 -1]))
        ns=list(G.nodes())
        G.add_edge(node_number, random.choice(ns))
        node_number += 1


s_pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'Position')
t_pos = nx.circular_layout(G)


def anim(t):
    global s_pos
    global t_pos
    interpolation = {i: s_pos[i]*(1-t/299) + t_pos[i] * t/299  for i in range(50)}
    plt.clf()
    plt.cla()
    nx.draw(G, pos=interpolation)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, anim, repeat=False, frames=300, interval=20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, @david ! It became much better. The only issue that I have now is that it starts with very tiny moves and as `t` goes up, the moves become better. I am wondering how I can make it more realistic. Something like JS-based tools. Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess this is because `circular_layout` extends between -1 and 1 and your source positions are a lot wider, so you have a unzoom  effect.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, @david. The speed is now changing uniformly, even in a couple of other layouts. I was able to speed up the transition by reducing the number of frames to 30, and tried to make it smooth by setting the interval to 1. However, it is still far less smooth than JS-based solutions. Is it because of clearing the plot area and redrawing, I mean the limitations of the matplotlib? I have not been able to find any pythonic solution for animating a network...

Comment: Don't forget that you can save in a GIF or MP4 format and the anination will be smoother than a Tk output, I think. But it's another problem... BTW, feel free to accept the answer ;-)

Comment: Oh, sure! Just did! Thanks for the help :-)